# why getBounds( ) of Drawable remains the same even after scaling?

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I used an ImageView to display a jpg file under my project 'assets' folder, the intrinsic dimensions are: 1280x854, which I confirmed by calling myDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() and myDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight().

My image view implemented pinch zoom so the image was scaled up to 2x for example. Then the following code got executed:

```
Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
Rect bounds =drawable.getBounds();
Log.i("activity", String.format("drawalbe : top:%d, left: %d, (%d, %d)", bounds.top, bounds.left, bounds.width(), bounds.height()));
```

the drawable bounds is always 1280x854 no matter what the current scale is, and the top, left is always 0, 0.

Isn't the bounds should be scaled accordingly? Could anyone give me some hints? Thank you.

Comment: what scale are you talking about ?

Comment: I am using ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener to get the scale factor and apply that factor to the image matrix. So say I have an image of 100x100 and after pinch zoom out the picture, the picture looks like 2x larger, in this case, I expect the drawable.getBounds() will be bigger. But in my case, the getBounds() always return the same size as the original size of the image.

Comment: so you are transforming the Matrix and it has nothing to do with Drawable bounds, why do you want Bounds to be changed ?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I wish to get: 1. the dimensions of the image drawable AFTER the scale.

Comment: @wizoleliam got any solution? can you help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376601/how-to-update-android-shapedrawable-bounds-changes-after-implimenting-scroller-w

Answer (score 1):

It's because of [this](http://debuggingisfun.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/android-when-scale-animations-wouldnt.html).

Scale matrix only affects how the view is drawn, but does not change its dimensions.

Although you can create a Rect of the size of your image and apply the same scale matrix to Rect with `Matrix.mapRect(Rect r)` and Rect will have the scaled dimensions.